# Why can't natural numbers be negative?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to figure out why can't Natural numbers be negative, following the axioms that can define real numbers and from them we can define natural numbers.
My book says that natural numbers can't be negative by saying that zero as no predecessor.

Thank you!

Comment: The issue is principally one of definition - how do you define the natural numbers?

Comment: @MarkBennet Well, for what I'm understanding any number is a natural number if  we x belongs to A and x+1 still belongs to A, right?

Comment: Have you encountered Peano's postulates? The issue behind the definitional one is that you need a base case as well as a successor case to make induction work. So you need somewhere to begin.

Comment: Call the natural numbers the "possible personalities of finite sets".  They can never be negative, right?  "Natural numbers" is just a catchier label that mathematicians like.

Comment: You can prove it by induction: $0\geq0$ and $1\geq0$. Assume that $n\geq0$, then adding this inequality with $1\geq0$ we get $n+1\geq0$. Therefore $n\geq0$ for all natural numbers. If $n\leq0$, since $n\geq0$, we should have $n=0$.

Comment: @MarkBennet First time hearing about that :/ So I just know that natural numbers are not negative?

Comment: You say you have induction: if $x \in \mathbb{N}$ then $x+1 \in \mathbb{N}$. That alone does not tell you that *anything* is in $\mathbb{N}$. But once you decide something (typically $0$ or $1$) is in $\mathbb{N}$ and then write down no more axioms, $\mathbb{N}$ then only continues infinitely to the right, and terminates somewhere on the left. By contrast, $\mathbb{Z}$ satisfies the "inductive property" as well.

Comment: The negative numbers, zero and the positive numbers form the set of the integers. This set has no open end. The set of natural numbers has a smallest element ($0$ or $1$).

Comment: I doubt that your book contains the quotation you attribute to it. Tell us what book you are using, and then we can comment on it. For everyone other than you and (perhaps) your book, the natural numbers are non-negative by definition.

Comment: @RobArthan I'm using a PDF from a book made by the math group from FCUL (engineering university from Portugal). My book doesn't say that natural numbers are negative.. I was just asking why couldn't they be :)

Comment: " I was just asking why couldn't they be"  For the same reason dogs can't be cats.  Because they aren't.

Comment: @fleablood I didn't know why it needed to be positive, the same way I didn't know why it couldn't be positive. Thanks for helping!!

Comment: Definitions are definitions.  They can be anything we want.  If we define things with successors but not predecessors and a place to stand and ... voila!  .... all natural numbers are positive successors to zero because ... we said so.  It's not any deeper than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your definition of natural numbers goes something similar to this.

1) if $x$ is a natural number then $x + 1$ is a natural number.

2) $0$ is a natural number.

3) The set of natural numbers has no other elements except those which rules 1 and 2 require to be.

Then negative numbers are not natural numbers for the same reason $\pi$ is not.  They don't have to be. They don't follow from rules 1) or 2) and thus are forbidden by rule 3).

Comment: Is 0 really natural?

Comment: Are platypuses really mammals?  Depends on your definition.  Change rule 2 to $1$ is a natural number, if you don't like $0$ being natural.  It's not relevant.  Point is negative numbers are not  naturals because .... we didn't want them to be.  Peanno postulates and induction definitions are often cleaner with 0 being natural but it's utterly arbitrary.

Comment: I would say that half the texts say 0 is natural and half don't.  Those that actually bother constructing and defining the naturals via axioms find it cleaner and neater to say 0 is natural.  Those that take the naturals as a given and like to use the natural numbers as an indexing for finite and countable sets find it more practical to say 0 is not.  It's the eternal counting headache.  How do you figure the numbers between $a$ and $b$? well... $b-a$.  ... plus or minus one depending on what "between" means... sigh... It hurt is the second grade, it hurts now.

Answer (score 3):

To summarise the comments:

Because they aren't, by definition.

Answer (score 0):

> following the axioms that can define real numbers and from them we can define natural numbers.

In my book it's the reverse. We first define the natural numbers, then the integers, then the rationals and lastly the reals.

> My book says that natural numbers can't be negative by saying that zero as no predecessor.

And your book is quite right. If you allow negative numbers you get the integers. However, many times the nonnegative integers are of interest. It's nice to have a specific name for that set. We call them the natural numbers.

So it's not really that the natural numbers have to be the way they are, but rather that we have this thing that we occasionally are interested in and we want to give this thing a name, and we call them the natural numbers.

Comment: I would argue the non-negatives include 0 and naturals don't

Comment: I have read some pages of the work of an Italian mathematician or team who constructs first the reals, and then derives the naturals. Unusual and very interesting ! Any one who gives us a reference ?

Comment: @Arthur , thank you for the help! :)

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee That's a matter of convention and context. I certainly know that I use both.